# How would i enable the Firefox apparmor profile in 22.04

Tags: firefox, snap, 22.04, apparmor, debugging

Ok so I found [this on the "How can I enable AppArmor for Firefox?" line](https://web.archive.org/web/20220407220232/https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor) on the Ubuntu wiki which is out of date because Firefox is now a snap.
I think the profile is enabled but first where is the profile with snaps I am not sure.

- Is the Firefox profile enabled in snap?
- Where are snap AppArmor profiles?

Answer (score 3):

While the documentation states (incorrectly) that apparmor profiles are stored in /etc/apparmor.d, this is not true for some profiles, especially for snaps. As explained on the [snapcraft.io forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/apparmor-profile-caching/1268/3) in 2017:

> Ubuntu’s apparmor init is patched to understand
> /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles and will load cache files from
> /var/cache/apparmor for those profiles (this concept dates back to
> Touch and snappy v1 (but they of course used different profile
> directories)). Profile caches for snappy end up there and apparmor
> init makes sure these are loaded on early boot.
>
> Note this will be problematic for non-Debian/non-Ubuntu systems that
> (will) use apparmor (eg, openSUSE).

The alternative location where snaps' apparmor profiles are stored is **not** documented on any Ubuntu site at present. I request that Ubuntu correct this omission, since their wiki page is immutable, and I can't correct it myself.

Comment: Finally I found this answer - I have been going crazy for the last hour looking for these profiles ^^ . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes the AppArmor Firefox Profile seems to be enabled, by default, at least on my 22.04 machine,

because I see some entries for Firefox in the kernel log files, entered by AppArmor:

```
zgrep firefox /var/log/kern.log*
```

Result (simplified, oneline -> multiline):

```
/var/log/kern.log.1:Jun 28 17:47:16 xxxx kernel: [ 6901.642471] 
apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.firefox.firefox" 
name="..." pid=7330 
comm="firefox" 
requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1001 ouid=0
```

I think the apparmor profile for the Firefox snap is in

`/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox`

and I think you can add your own rules in

`/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.bin.firefox`

which by default only contains these comments (on my 22.04)

```
# Site-specific additions and overrides for usr.bin.firefox.                    
# For more details, please see /etc/apparmor.d/local/README.
```

But I do not know how to do that, adding custom rules.

- *The /etc/apparmor.d directory is **not** used for snaps (see my answer).*