# Teach Firefox snap on 22.04 which applications are available to open which files, with PDF as an example

Tags: firefox, 22.04, snap, pdf, apparmor

With firefox from snap on a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04, the browser does not know any application to open a pdf.

I have configured 'always ask' and get the dialogs shown below when clicking on a pdf. Since evince and qpdfview are installed, they should appear in the 'Select Application' dialog.

**Question:** Can anyone explain where firefox learns which applications are available and how this can be fixed?

While [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1428798/367444) discusses possibilities to get evince to work in firefox, I am interested in the more fundamental question of how firefox learns which applications may be used to open what?

Further [snap firefox apparmor](https://askubuntu.com/a/1425532/367444) profiles are probably related. In `/var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles` there are 7 files with `firefox` in the name, totaling 11953 lines. :-/

Please don't get distracted by 'localhost' and 'http' as the pdf source. The same happens with downloads from public site with https and valid certificates.
[image]

Comment: I wonder if getting rid of snap-firefox and install via apt is the only solution here.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1428798/367444 may be related, but i don't even get `evince` shown as one option and cannot even configure it to be used in firefox settings.